# Find limit with ε − δ arguments

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Determine $\lim_{x \to p} f(x)$  justifying your answer with $\varepsilon$−$\delta$ arguments.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2−1}$$

$p = 0$;

I only managed so far:

$$\frac{x^2} {x^2-1} <  \varepsilon$$

How do i simplify this expression to make it       $x <\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I cannot see any good reason to be concerned whether $x<\epsilon.$ Even if you meant $x<\delta,$ you’re asking the wrong question. You don’t need to “simplify” the inequality you found, which would give you something equivalent to it; you only need something that **implies** it.

Comment: I wrote wrong
  x  <  c . ϵ, dont need simplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I wish students would realize is that *figuring* out how to do a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof is working backwards and what you end up is rough draft of a proof that you use to make a final proof.

In this case the *final* proof will go like this.

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{x^2 - 1} = -1$.

Proof:  For any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = \min(\sqrt{\frac 34 \epsilon}, \frac 12)$.

If $|x-0| < \delta;x\ne 0$ then $|x| < \frac 12$ and $x^2 < \frac 14$ and $1> 1-x^2 > \frac 34$

But as $0<|x| < \delta$ we have

$|x^2| < \delta^2 < \frac 34\epsilon < |1-x^2|\epsilon$.

So $\frac {|x^2|}{|1-x^2|}< \epsilon$

And $|\frac 1{x^2-1}-(-1)|=|\frac {x^2}{x^2-1}|=\frac {|x^2|}{|1-x^2|}< \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{x^2 - 1} = -1$.

....

So the question is how the heck did we figure out to let $\delta = \min(\sqrt{\frac 43 \epsilon}, \frac 12)$ and how did we figure to do the manipulations.

ANd that was:

Firs $\frac 1{0^2 -1} =-1$ so we figure the limit has to be $-1$.

We want to *end* with $|\frac 1{x^2 -1} -(-1)| < \epsilon$.

And that is $|\frac 1{x^2 -1} -(-1)|=|\frac {x^2}{x^2-1}| < \epsilon$ so

$|x^2| < |x^2 - 1|\epsilon$.

Now we can make $|x-0| < \delta$ as small as we like so if make it really small then $|x^2 -1|$ can be really close to $1$.  If we, for example make $\delta \le \frac 12$ then $|x^2 -1| \ge \frac 34$ so we can get

$|x^2| < |x^2 - 1| \epsilon \le \frac 34 \epsilon$.

So If we have $|x^2| < \delta^2 \le \frac 34 \epsilon$

then it will work.

So if we have $\delta \le \frac 12$ and $\delta \le \sqrt{\frac 34\epsilon}$ it will work.  Thus our chose of $\delta = \min(\frac 12,\sqrt{\frac 34\epsilon}$.  And our final proof.

Comment: I personally never allowed roots of $\epsilon$ to appear in the formula for $\delta$, since continuity is required to justify their existence in the first place. But all these proofs can be rewritten to have $\delta$ linear in $\epsilon$. In your case, note that with the preliminary assumption that $\delta<1/2$, we have $|x^2|<|x|$ whenever $|x|<\delta$.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right.  My first writting had $|x|^2 < |x|  < \delta \le \frac 34\epsilon$ but .... I figured as I was showing how to use the figure out that $\delta$ as a "draft" I should do an actually heavy duty calculation.... Actually, I'm not sure I see the problem with continuity. As $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are positive I don't see how root of epsilon is a problem (provided you get it legitimately).

Answer (score 0):

You can intuitively see that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) = -1$. In consequence, what you are looking for is to prove that for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$x\in (-\delta,\delta) \Rightarrow \left| -1 - f(x) \right| < \varepsilon.$$

The last inequality can be rewritten as $\left| -1 - \dfrac{1}{x^2-1} \right| < \varepsilon$, which in turn is $\left| - \dfrac{x^2}{x^2-1} \right| < \varepsilon$.

**Note:** when dealing with limits we consider $\varepsilon, \delta$ to be very small, close to 0. In consequence, we expect $x \approx 0 < 1$, hence $x^2-1 < 0$. Thus, our absolute value relation can be transformed as follows
$$\dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2} < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow x^2 < \varepsilon-x^2\varepsilon \Leftrightarrow (1+\varepsilon)x^2 < \varepsilon.$$

Now, as $\varepsilon \approx 0 < 1$, we have $(1+\varepsilon)x^2 < 2x^2$. Thus, it is sufficient to find an $x$ such that $2x^2 < \varepsilon$.

So, if we consider $\delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon/2}$, we have for any $x\in (-\delta,\delta)$ that $x^2 < \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$, therefore $(1+\varepsilon)x^2 < \varepsilon$ and the limit can be proven.

Hope it helps and clarifies a bit the thought process!

Comment: $\frac{x^{2}}{1-x^{2}}$ is not lesser than $x^{2}$ for small $x$.

Comment: This is not a valid argument. I suggest you try to fix it: If $|x|<1/2$, then $1-x^2>3/4$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Thank you for the comments; corrected the answer following the same reasoning :)